# In Vega-lite, how do I filter by time?

Tags: vega-lite

I have a CSV with a row per 15-minute interval and columns for metrics like airflow and temperature. I'd like to filter the data so I can plot only the most recent day or week.

How do I add a filter for a date (Mar 9) or date range (Mar 6–12)? Is it more common to do filtering and aggregation (to hourly or daily averages) before handing the data to Vega-Lite?

Here's my code without a filter:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": "Average Airflow",
  "description": "Average Airflow in Rooms",
  "data": {"url": "hvac_data-wide.csv"},
  "mark": "line",
  "width": 608,
  "height": 342,
  "transform": [{
    "timeUnit":"dayhours",
    "field": "Date",
    "as": "hours"
  }],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "hours", "type": "temporal", "title": "Time"},
    "y": {"field": "SaFl", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "mean", "title": "Source Air CFM"},
    "color": {"field": "Floor", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

Here's some sample data:

```
Date,Category,Floor,Name,HVACModeStatus,RmTmp,SaFl,EaFl,CO2,NPW,ChW,wh,kwh
2022-03-07 08:10,zone,1,Lab1115,4,70.88,374.717,1109.641,,,,,
2022-03-07 08:10,zone,1,Lab1121,4,70.16,1700.559,1897.229,,,,,
2022-03-07 08:10,zone,1,Lab1126,2,73.22,1061.672,1572.01,,,,,
2022-03-07 08:15,zone,1,Lab1115,4,70.88,349.848,1170.564,,,,,
2022-03-07 08:15,zone,1,Lab1121,4,70.16,1699.6,1870.382,,,,,
2022-03-07 08:15,zone,1,Lab1126,2,73.22,1092.875,1606.451,,,,,
2022-03-07 08:20,zone,1,Lab1115,4,70.88,376.867,1156.398,,,,,
2022-03-07 08:20,zone,1,Lab1121,4,70.16,1692.929,1875.636,,,,,
2022-03-07 08:20,zone,1,Lab1126,2,73.22,1148.222,1580.696,,,,,
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Filters can be added within the transform.

Here's code to show a date range filter:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": "Average Airflow",
  "description": "Average Airflow in Rooms",
  "data": {"url": "hvac_data-wide.csv"},
  "mark": "line",
  "width": 608,
  "height": 342,
  "transform": [
    {
      "timeUnit":"dayhours",
      "field": "Date",
      "as": "hours"
    },
    {"filter": {"field": "Date", 
    "range": [  {"year": 2022, "month": 3, "date": 8, "hours": 0},
                {"year": 2022, "month": 3, "date": 8, "hours": 24, "minutes": 59}]}}
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "hours", "type": "temporal", "title": "Time"},
    "y": {"field": "SaFl", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "mean", "title": "Exhaust CFM"},
    "color": {"field": "Floor", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

They can also be simple expression string, substitute this filter block: `{ "filter": "datum.Floor == 3"}`

Or a primitive: `{ "filter": {"field": "Floor", "equal": 3}}`

More info about filters on the Vega-Lite docs [Predicate page](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/predicate.html).